# PHP On Windows: Blank .php files load slowly, blank .html files load quickly

Tags: php, performance, iis-6

I'm working on a site that was recently converted to PHP (used to be VB.net), and the new PHP site is running ridiculously slowly (insert PHP joke here).

www.silhouetteonlinestore.com

So the first thing I did was I went about optimizing my code, making tweaks in every place that I could find, but it didn't help more than maybe 50 milliseconds on the load time. Then I took off URL rewrites in web.config, and that actually did cut the load time in half, but it still wasn't acceptable.

Then I found this:

- www.silhouetteonlinestore.com/php/test.php (runs slow)
- www.silhouetteonlinestore.com/php/test.html (runs fast)
- www.silhouetteonlinestore.com/php/test.aspx (runs fast)

All three of the above files run the same static HTML code with the word "test" in the  tags, but the PHP one runs slow! The test version of the site with the same configuration, on the same server, runs lightning-quick, so whatever the problem is seems to be exacerbated by extra traffic on the site. But we don't have millions hitting the site or anything--we average 300-500 users browsing the site at any given moment.

The configuration:

- PHP 5.2.17 on IIS 6.0, using FastCGI
- Hosted on Windows 2008 server, with Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2374 HE 2.20 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 64-bit OS

I'm not very experienced with server administration, so any help is appreciated. My first hunch is to upgrade to PHP 5.4.4, because there may be compatibility issues there, so I'm going to work on that; I tried to do that a while back and I couldn't get it to work properly (phpinfo() revealed that some settings still thought it was 5.2, and I think there was an environment variable that wasn't set or something).

Let me know what other critical information I left out; I really appreciate your time!

Comment: PHP runs fine on most servers, so it's most likely a PEBKAC situation. Server configuration is offtopic for this site. Try serverfault, maybe.

Comment: "PHP 5.2.17 on **IIS 6.0**" is probably your problem. Can't you run on (or at least test on) Nginx or Apache?

Comment: @DaveRandom I can test on Apache, but it's hard to tell whether there is a problem without the traffic on the site; our current test configuration works great, just not the live one.

Comment: Can you at least run a version of PHP which is still supported?

Comment: @MichaelHampton In the process of updating PHP now.

Comment: For future reference, the answer was that I needed to change the FastCGI settings to allow additional instances of FastCGI. Apparently, it's generally recommended that you allow 10x the number of processors, which would equal 40 for us. We had it set to 4, ha ha.

As an aside, while I understand why this might be flagged as off-topic if we need to stick to programming questions, I see hundreds of similar topics not flagged as such on this site, which gave me the idea to post here.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out what is causing the issue you should try the following:

1. You need to look at the PHP strict, notice, error and warning messages. You can do this by editing your PHP.ini. See [The errorfunction section](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) of the PHP manual. Note I would actually edit the php.ini file and not use [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) because the issue might occur before the first call to `ini_set()` happens.
2. Install [PHP Manager for IIS](http://phpmanager.codeplex.com/) and look at the warning in the section it adds to IIS manager. It will make several suggestions as to whats wrong with your php.ini file. I've never seen it detect a problem that was slowing down PHP significantly, but its certainly possible it might.
3. Profile the calls to php.exe with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) see if there are any failed calls to files or the like.

Comment: Great ideas. I will look at these and see what I can learn from them. Thank you!